# Implementing a PasswordChar property to my custom C# Windows Form TextBox class that supports placeholders

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, passwords, placeholder

I'm trying to implement a PasswordChar property to my TextBox class that cooperates with my Placeholder class. This is my code:

```
class MyTextBox : TextBox
{
    public Placeholder Placeholder;

    public MyTextBox()
    {
        Placeholder = new Placeholder(this);

        GotFocus += new EventHandler(_GotFocus);
        LostFocus += new EventHandler(_LostFocus);
    }

    private void _GotFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Placeholder.Active = false;
    }

    private void _LostFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Text))
            Placeholder.Active = true;
    }
}

class Placeholder
{
    private MyTextBox textBox;
    private bool active = false;
    public bool Active
    {
        get { return active; }
        set
        {
            if (value)
            {
                textBox.ForeColor = ForeColor;
                textBox.Text = Text;
            }
            else if (active && !value)
            {
                textBox.ForeColor = previousForeColor;
                textBox.Text = string.Empty;
            }

            active = value;
        }
    }
    private Color previousForeColor;
    private Color foreColor = Color.Gray;
    public Color ForeColor
    {
        get { return foreColor; }
        set
        {
            previousForeColor = ForeColor;
            ForeColor = value;
        }
    }
    private string text = "Placeholder";
    public string Text
    {
        get { return text; }
        set
        {
            text = value;

            if (active)
                textBox.Text = Text;
        }
    }

    public Placeholder(MyTextBox textBox)
    {
        this.textBox = textBox;
    }
}
```

The way I want it to work is if I set the TextBox's property PasswordChar to anything but '\0' then it should be set to '\0' when the TextBox's property's Placeholder's property Active is true, and should be set back to whatever the PasswordChar was when it's set to false.
In other words, if PasswordChar is set then unmask the text when the Active property is true, and remask the text when it's set back to false.

Comment: Off-topic: Your classes Placeholder and MyTextbox are so heavily intertwined I don't see why you need to separate them in two classes. It merely adds unnecessary complexity and a false sense of seperate concerns. Also what does your Forecolor-property do? It sets itself

Comment: You are right, thank you for pointing that out. The ForeColor property sets the TextBox's ForeColor to the passed value and stores the TextBox's previous ForeColor in a field so it can be set back to when the Placeholder is deactivated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds as simple as storing the original `PasswordChar` in a temporary variable:

```
class Placeholder
{
    private MyTextBox textBox;
    private bool active = false;
    private char? originalPasswordChar = null;
    public bool Active
    {
        get { return active; }
        set
        {
            if (value)
            {
                textBox.ForeColor = ForeColor;
                textBox.Text = Text;
                if (originalPasswordChar == null) originalPasswordChar = textBox.PasswordChar;
            }
            else if (active && !value)
            {
                textBox.ForeColor = previousForeColor;
                textBox.Text = string.Empty;
                textBox.PasswordChar = originalPasswordChar.Value;
                originalPasswordChar = null; 
            }

            active = value;
        }
    }
    // (...)
}
```